# Vuex and the mutate thing, the immutability and the clone deep hell

Tags: immutability, vuex

This is not a questions itself, but a good issue to Vue community. I want to open a discussion about Vuex and immutability. When we enable Vuex **strict mode** and when we have within the state an object called by a computed function that we need to change its properties into a component, we are warned not to take this practice. Ok, this is not new...

I got the point of it and I am convinced that it is for the best, but I find myself having to clone (**deep clone**) the object into a computed/data in order to be able to work with a local state without mutante it directly.

So I have a question: since it is not a good practice to mutate the properties of an object directly and since I have to use `this.$store.commit` / `this.$store.disptach` to mutante the state, why Vuex does not deliver a **deep clone** of this object instead of a **shallow clone** when we call the state by `this.$store.state` or `this.$store.getters` within a computed.

[vue-freeze](http://bosnaufal.github.io/vue-freeze/) is a module that tries to react to this issue, but it is not update since a long time. How do you folks work with this?